# Reposition Messi-ask box

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms

I have some code that displays a Messi.ask box on a button click event. The code works perfectly in terms of displaying the correct message and the buttons work as needed on the confirmation box however, the position of the box is off-center and I'm not sure how to reposition it. Can someone please assist with anything to help me.

Messi box code:

```
function confirmQuickAppointEmployee(message, url) {
    Messi.ask(message,
        function (val) {
            if (val) {
                window.location.href = url;
            }

        }, {
        buttons: [{ id: 'confirm', label: 'Confirm', val: true, 'class': 'btn-primary' }, { id: 'cancel', label: 'Cancel', val: false }]
    });
}
```

Where the box is currently positions:

[image]

Comment: please provide the html code about the Messi-ask box.

Comment: There is no HTML code. Only a JS script @JackJJun-MSFT